# Link SQL results to each other

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

Users

```
id, first, last
1   John   Johnsson
2   Mark   Jackson
3   Chris  Lager
```

Tags

```
id, userID, tag,       pass,        active
1   2       42564eb6   <some hash>  1
2   1       524846b6   <some hash>  0
```

What i want to output is this combination of data:

Tags

```
ID(from user), First name, Last name, Tag number, Password hash, Active
1              John        Johnsson   524846b6    <hash>         0
2              Mark        Jackson    42564eb6    <hash>         1
3              Chris       Lager
```

So basically, I want a table with users, ordered by their ID's, with the `tag number`, `pass` and `active` fields if applicable

I'm using webbased databases with PHPMyAdmin on an external server, and I am querying on it in Java through JDBC.

My question: what query do I need to use for this? I'm not really sure what commands such as `Group By` or `Order By` will do with my data, which comes in as a `ResultSet` object in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a LEFT JOIN, eg:

```
select
u.id,
u.first as [First Name],
u.Last as [Last name],
t.tag as [Tag Number],
t.pass as [Password],
t.Active
FROM [user] as u
LEFT JOIN [Tags] T ON U.id=T.UserId
ORDER BY u.[id] ASC
```

Comment: Please edit your answer so the `ORDER BY` is included in the answer text. Afterwards your can delete your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

`SELECT u.*, t.tag, t.pass, t.active FROM users u INNER JOIN tags t ON u.id = t.userID ORDER BY u.id`

Comment: This will not order the result on user IDs, I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.ID AS UserID, U.First AS FirstName, U.Last AS LastName, 
       T.Tag AS TagNumber, T.Password AS PasswordHash, T.Active
FROM `Users` U
INNER JOIN `Tags` T ON T.UserID = U.ID
ORDER BY U.ID
```

Comment: I think result will not be in sorted order of users.ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [SQL Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) to do this on tables.  The code for your question is:

```
select
    users.id
    , users.first
    , users.last
    , tags.tag
    , tags.pass
    , tags.active
from
    users
    , tags
where
    users.id = tags.userID
order by
    users.id
/
```

Comment: This won't include the `Users` without `Tags`. I think one of the other answers is better. Still, thank you for your time :)